# html5 canvas for multiple choice?

Tags: html, canvas

is it possible for create a multiple choice / trivia on html5 canvas?
there will be guessing image along the multiplechoices
(the content will not only text)
for example it contains 30 questions
and randomly show 10 questions, 1 question per screen (like, if done answering one question, the screen will slide to another question - the another questions are hidden)

I googled and it comes to using an app like appcobra something something
but I can't using app to create html5 canvas implementation,

and if it's possible so, is there any tutorial or reference to learn about it?
thank you in advance.
:)

Comment: It's like asking if it's possible to make a video game with Photoshop. Well, yes, but it's just one piece of the larger puzzle.

Comment: You might have a look at my [**canvas GUI**](http://cssdeck.com/labs/ebmkdf4p) work in progress to aid you. Most of what I have could be taken out in your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just recently finished an HTML5 canvas project requiring questions and buttons.Audio would play when you arrived on a question page, and then you could click A,B,C,D and it would check if you got the answer right.
I found no tutorial on specifically what you are looking for.

The primary thing that you will use html5 canvas for is displaying the questions, and detecting user interaction.

Create a layer for each element: text, background, buttons.

Use canvastext.com for the text, it helps with word wrap and styling.

Then you can either use gradients or images as the buttons. You will need to have a listener that detects the mouse click in the coordinate of where the button was pressed.

Let me know if you have any specific questions on how to do the above. 
I also created a java applet exactly as you described. I could not find any online tutorials for it either, but it was easier to program bc I am more comfortable w/ java.

Comment: yes that's what I want to make. It's just.. I want to make it in/using  html5 canvas.. some other source tell me to use js, I mean that okay too, but can it inside canvas or something... can you help me out for this? since your description match 100% what I want to make :D or any email I can contact you? thank you in advance

Comment: woodlumhoodlum@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

It's fully possible but as canvas is a passive element (it doesn't know about its content other than it being a pixel buffer) you will need to implement the button logic yourself.

I would in this case recommend using plain HTML(5) and CSS3 (which support animation which you can use to make slide effects etc.).

However as you ask for canvas, here's an example for button click detection which you could adopt to your needs -

Define the button areas:

```
var buttons = [
    [10, 10, 50, 30],
    [70, 10, 50, 30],
    [130, 10, 50, 30]
];
```

Render the buttons:

```
for(; b = buttons[i]; i++)
    ctx.rect(b[0], b[1], b[2], b[3]);

/// simple buttons in this example..
ctx.fillStyle = '#F90';
ctx.fill();
```

Now you can tap into the click callback (or if you want to change color on mouse down instead use onmousedown/up callbacks):

```
canvas.onclick = function(e) {

    /// adjust mouse position to relative to canvas:
    var r = canvas.getBoundingClientRect(),
        x = e.clientX - r.left,
        y = e.clientY - r.top,
        i = 0, b;

    /// check if x/y is within any of the buttons
    for(; b = buttons[i]; i++) {
        if (x > b[0] && x < b[0] + b[2] &&
            y > b[1] && y < b[1] + b[3]) {

            /// we got a hit - handle button
            alert('Button ' + i + ' was clicked!');
            return;
        }
    }    
}
```

**[Here is an online demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/PGmpm/)**.